# SAML Claims with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sso

Looking through the documentation on configuring SharePoint 2013 to use ADFS or to use OneLogin. I noticed that in the documentation for defining the identity and role claim mappings with ADFS that they use UPN as a claim mapping. When looking at the documentation for OneLogin I see that they use the ROLE claim mapping. Samples below

```
$upnClaimMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "UPN" –SameAsIncoming
```

or

```
$role=New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Role" -SameAsIncoming
```

My question is what is difference between UPN and ROLE, why would one be used vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its simplest form, claims are simply statements (for example, name, identity, group), made about users, that are used primarily for authorizing access to claims-based applications located anywhere on the Internet. Each statement corresponds to a value that is stored in the claim.

It is depend, A claim type provides context for the claim value. It is usually expressed as a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI). AD FS can support any claim type, and it is configured with the claim types in the following table by default.

**UPN = The user principal name (UPN) of the user**

**Role = A role that the user has**

Read this technet about more about claims types and all available  claim type.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913589.aspx

Comment: Ok that makes sense now that i've seen how they break down...so is it possible to setup SAML authentication in SP2013 to just use the Email Address claim type? instead of email and UPN as the guides i've found show? What happens if your just using email for claims?

Comment: Hi Jacob, you can use email address for your claim. You just need to claim rule in relying party trust in AD FS.Have a look this article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913565.aspx